# 'Toggle System Console' is not in the window tab

Tags: command-line, system

v2.82a mac osx high sierra.

Anyway to turn this on elsewhere?
I've tried the search menu and check earlier versions.

Thanks

Comment: This option is only available on Windows. On macOS you have to open a terminal and start Blender from there.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thanks! Had to do this to get my old Adobe CS5 to work. Same solution to a different problem.

Comment: Additional info as I ran into the same problem: you need to go to where Blender.app is located (normally in /Applications). If you execute `>open Blender.app` you will see nothing. You need to navigate deeper to `Blender.app/Contents/MacOS` and execute `>open Blender` from there.